# Excess charge on a conducting Disk

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

I understand the concept of excess charge to be on the outside surface of the conductor. What happens if conductor is a 2 dimensional conducting Disk and 1 dimensional conducting needle?

I am reading Griffiths and he seems to mention in a footnote that above cases will different without giving much details.

Comment: The dimensions of the thinnest conducting sheets is way larger than electron dimensions. This is a highly unrealistc situation, and probably does not have a very intuitive picture.

Comment: -1. No effort made to look for a solution online.

Answer (score 0):

Both problems are quite difficult.

The solution for the conducting disk is well-established and is given in [Conducting Ellipsoid and Conducting Disk](http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/ellipsoid.pdf). The 1D needle could be modelled as an ellipsoid, then the same solution could be used.

If you [google "charge density on conducting needle"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Excess+charge+on+a+conducting+Disk&oq=Excess+charge+on+a+conducting+Disk&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=charge+density+on+a+conducting+needle) you will find that there may not be a consensus about the solution for the 1D needle.

[Griffiths' own conclusion (1996)](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys3320/phys3320_sp12/AJPPapers/AJP_E&MPapers_030612/Griffiths_ConductingNeedle.pdf) was that the problem "might be ill-posed." [Mark Andrews (1997)](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.18671) considered the charge distribution on needle-like objects and decided that the distribution "must be uniform, except close to the ends."

[Bonfim & Griffiths (2000)](http://pilotscholars.up.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=phy_facpubs) revisited and confirmed the solution provided by JD Jackson (also in 2000). Jackson concluded that the ellipsoid solution holds for the cylinder also, and that although charge density is higher at the ends, the ends hold a decreasing fraction of total charge - so, contrary to intuition, charge does not accumulate preferentially at the sharp ends.

Comment: Thanks It was very helpful. I wasnt able to follow the whole derivation for the disk but looks like it is going to uniform. Is that correct .?

Comment: No. Eqn #3 in Kirk McDonald's problem sheet states that surface charge density increases towards the edge of the disk, where it is infinite.

Comment: thx so much. It was very helpful.

Comment: More I think about disk, I have having more questions. So in stead of a 2 D disk, I have a thick rectangular slab of conductor  and I place some excess charge, the excess charge would go on the both outer  surfaces of the slab. Is that right.? I guess the confusion is outer and inner surface is generally with closed surfaces. In this case, it is thick slab so what is outer and what is inner .?

Comment: Excess charge on a conductor stays on the surface. A slab or disk has front and back faces, and also edges. There will be charge on each of these surfaces. I do not understand what distinction you are making about outer and inner surfaces.